# Get one elements inside <tb> with Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

im new to Python and im trying to make a web scraper to get the name and the ip of Minecraft server.

The problem is that I was able to get the value of the  but for example the ip of the server is in a div inside de 
Im using pandas and lxml.html

example:

```
<tr>
        <td class="server-rank visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
            <p><a href="#1.akumamc.net"><span class="badge">#1</span></a></p>
        </td>

        <td class="server-name" align="center"> 
           <div class="server-ip input-group">
              <p> this is de ip of the server <p>     -I WANT TO GET HERE-
           </div> 
        </td>
</tr>
```

I dont know how to make to the div inside the tb.
I have this script that I took from a page that works perfect to the other things but not for getting to the inside.

```
from numpy import tile
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import re

#https://www.servidoresminecraft.info/1.8/

url='https://topminecraftservers.org/version/1.8.8'
#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
page = requests.get(url)
#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')



#Check the length of the first 12 rows
[len(T) for T in tr_elements[:5]]

tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
#Create empty list
col=[]
i=0
#For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    print ('%d:"%s"'%(i,name))
    col.append((name,[]))

#Since out first row is the header, data is stored on the second row onwards
for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)):
    #T is our j'th row
    T=tr_elements[j]
    
    #If row is not of size 10, the //tr data is not from our table 
    if len(T)!=3:
        break
    
    #i is the index of our column
    i=0
    
    #Iterate through each element of the row
    for t in T.iterchildren():
        data=t.text_content() 
        #Check if row is empty
        if i>0:
        #Convert any numerical value to integers
            try:
                if i==2 and j == 1:
                    print(2)
                data=int(data)
            except:
                pass
        #Append the data to the empty list of the i'th column
        col[i][1].append(data)
        #Increment i for the next column
        i+=1

[len(C) for (title,C) in col]

Dict={title:column for (title,column) in col}
df=pd.DataFrame(Dict)


print(df.head())
```

I just want to get and aotput thats shows the a table with the name of the server and the ip

```
Name      ip
server1   xxx.xxx.x.x
server2   xxx.xxx.x.x
```

Any help??

Comment: Are you trying to get only the server names (`akumak.net`,`lunixcraft,dk`, etc.) or more than that? Please edit your question and add a sample of the expected output.

Comment: @JackFleeting there you have it

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, only two servers on the page have the actual IP address; the others only have server names.

Comment: @JackFleeting No, a mincraft sever ip can be like akumamc.net or like 192.168.1.1

Comment: Then with most servers, you'll get a table where `Name` and `ip` are the same - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, because for example the ip of Akumak is akumak.net but he ip of BattleAysa is play.battleasya.com. The ips not allways are the same as the ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should get you what you're looking for:

```
servers = []
cols = ["Name", "ip"]
for s in doc.xpath("//td[@class='server-name']"):
    s_ip = s.xpath(".//div[@class='server-ip input-group']//span[@class='form-control text-justify']/text()")[0]
    s_name = s.xpath('.//h4/a/span/text()')[0]
    servers.append([s_name,s_ip])
pd.DataFrame(servers, columns = cols)
```

Output:

```
    Name                          ip
0   AkumaMC                       akumamc.net
1   BattleAsya 1.8-1.16           play.battleasya.com
2   Caraotacraft network PRISON   caraotacraft.top
3   FlameSquad                    87.121.54.214:25568
4   LunixCraft                    lunixcraft.dk
```

etc.

Comment: bro you amazing

Comment: @JuanGarcia Glad it worked for you!